# how to add emoticons in my java chat messenger

Tags: java, emoticons

I am making a LAN messenger using java. I want to add the emoticons that are normally used in any basic messenger. I am using sockets. I have seen the solution where we use the JEditorPane with StyledEditorKit. But I dont want to use Graphics. I have also seen the unicode method. 
Is there any other way to do it where I can display the emoticons in a list and a user can click on them to use them or simply if a user types " :) "  then the smiley is displayed in the sent/received window.
Using     jTextArea for displaying

Below are the components that make up my client window.

```
public javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
public javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
public javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
public javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
public javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
public javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
public javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
public javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
public javax.swing.JList jList1;
public javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator2;
public javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell without code or deeper description of your program. What are you using to output the text ?

Comment: I am using the jTextArea for displaying the messages to the user.
so a simple "  jTextArea.append "is being used to display the messages that is received from the server

Comment: You cannot display image nor drawing inside a `JTextArea` so you will have to use `Graphics` from a Swing compoent to render text and image

Comment: @ortis   But if I use **Graphics** then I will have to use **JEditorPane** along with **StyledEditorKit** in place of **jTextArea** and for that I will have to change a lot of code.
Is there a way to do it with **jTextArea**  ?

Comment: No, neither `JEditorPane` nor StyledEditorKit are mandatory for that. You can call `Component.getGraphics()`  (from a `JPanel` for example) and then use `Graphics.drawString()` and `Graphics.drawImage()` to render text and image.

Comment: @ortis   I have edited my post and included the components that make up my client window. Can I add use graphics with the components that I have or do I have to add some new components or edit the existing ones.

Comment: I guess you have a `JPanel` too. Just override the `JPanel.paint()` method and use the methods I mentioned.

Comment: I dont have a     JPanel.   I have JFrame.

Comment: `JFrame` will works too but it is bad practise to put anything else than `JPanel` in a `JFrame`

Comment: Alright. I will give it a try and see what happens. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for JTextPane.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Comment: I have edited my post and added the components that I currently have in my client window. Could you tell me if I need to add any new component or edit any existing one..